# Selenium in Java - number of elements returned is greater than that on page

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

The below portion of HTML comes from the search results of AboutYou.de (https://www.aboutyou.de/suche?term=hemd&category=20202) - a site I am trying to scrape. I have determined the a element to each item begins with a href="/p/. There are 98 in the page source.
For example, this is one item:

```
<a href="/p/hugo/buegelleichtes-hemd-elvor-3636873">
```

To get these 98 items, I am using the following lines of code in my Java app:

```
List<WebElement> pageContent = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

pageContent.addAll(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/p/']")));
```

The result is 196, or two times as many as are actually present. In fact, if I use a query matching, for example, 10 elements, Selenium will return 20, and so on. The size of the List will always be twice that of matching a elements. How do I get only 98 and make sure these are the ones I actually intend on working with?

Comment: in your browser console, try running this:  `document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='/p/']").length` what number do you get

Comment: It is 196. But if a search is initiated through CTRL + F, the result is 98, which what I get if I simply count the number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because for every artikel there are two links, one on the image and one on the title of the artikel.
You can use a more specific path like :

```
List<WebElement> pageContent = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

pageContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/p/')][@class='product-name-link']");
```

html example

```
<article id="product-3636873" class="js-productlist-product productlist-product isLayout3  " data-product-id="3636873" data-product-variant="33638894" data-product-brand="3083">
    <div class="badges">
        <ul class="badges-list category-badges-list">
                                </ul>
        <ul class="badges-list js-badges-list">
                        <li><span class="badge sale js-badge-sale hidden" data-original="hidden"></span></li>
                            <li><span class="badge new js-badge-new">Neu</span></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="js-wishlist-button-region wishlist-button-region"></div>
    <div class="product-image loaded  ">
```

> ```
>       <a href="/p/hugo/buegelleichtes-hemd-elvor-3636873">
> ```

```
                        <picture>
                <source srcset="//cdn.aboutyou.de/file/78305ba727523be0c92ec529b9776f17?bg=ffffff&amp;height=400&amp;progressive=1&amp;quality=90&amp;trim=1&amp;width=400 1x, //cdn.aboutyou.de/file/78305ba727523be0c92ec529b9776f17?bg=ffffff&amp;height=600&amp;progressive=1&amp;quality=90&amp;trim=1&amp;width=600 2x">
                <img src="//cdn.aboutyou.de/file/78305ba727523be0c92ec529b9776f17?bg=ffffff&amp;height=400&amp;progressive=1&amp;quality=90&amp;trim=1&amp;width=400" data-src="//cdn.aboutyou.de/file/78305ba727523be0c92ec529b9776f17?bg=ffffff&amp;height=400&amp;progressive=1&amp;quality=90&amp;trim=1&amp;width=400" class="product-original js-productlist-previewimage loaded" width="245" height="211" alt="HUGO Bügelleichtes Hemd 'Elvor'">
            </picture>
                    </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Adding new thumbs for touch devices -->
    <div class="js-product-touch-variants product-touch-variants">
    </div>

    <!-- TODO: need to get real data here and show it only if campaign is active otherwise hidden -->
        <div class="js-product-name product-name">
        <div itemprop="name">
```

> ```
> <a class="product-name-link" itemprop="url" href="/p/hugo/buegelleichtes-hemd-elvor-3636873">Bügelleichtes Hemd 'Elvor'</a>
> ```

```
</div>
    </div>
        <div class="product-brand">
        <div itemprop="brand"><a class="js-product-item-brand" href="?gender=null">HUGO</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-product-price product-price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR"><h5 class="price actual-price actual-price" itemprop="price" content="69.90">
    <span class="price-data currency isEUR" data-original="69,90€" data-price="69,90€">69,90</span>
</h5>
    </div>
</article>
```